# Doesn't this method of Machine Learning do perfectly fine?

Tags: machine-learning

There's many types of Machine Learning methods, but one sticks in my mind, and I don't understand why for ex. Q Learning was made instead of just using the following method:

Method:
Say we give the robot some Triggers, we will implant a pre-installed image of a girl, taste of fries, sound of birds, and acceleration. When it Guesses Actions - that get a trigger, it saves actions just done and links them to senses just saved and labels the senses&actions as + or - based on if matched a + or - trigger and gives it a rating of how much it matched, then when it senses it again later, it matches memory and links to the actions and they are initiated, it walks to the girl/sound of birds chirping.

Seeing that, why is Q Learning so complex the way it works?

Comment: You sound very naive. Try implementing such a system to see what goes wrong.

Comment: By image matching I mean scaling/rotating/tranlating/ect and the more that matches the more it saves guessed actions. By Q Learning I meant what else besides finding pixel patterns could it be doing?

Comment: Again, you must explain what will "not work". My method isn't perpetual motion, it does-work.

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is similar to what virus detection software does. It is given a list of signatures and then searches for them in its input stream. In contrast, machine learning works in a setting in which you don't expect identical inputs to typically appear. For example, consider the task of recognizing digits. Here are some examples of the digit 2, from a paper of [Mayraz and Hinton](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~fritz/absps/guypami.pdf):

[image: The digit 2]

None of these is identical to the others. Suppose that you only train your learner with the upper half. When encountering a digit from the bottom half, how would you recognize it as 2? You need to generalize your training examples. This is what machine learning is about.

Comment: Mhm, I think you better re-analyze my whole opening post again, it isn't waiting for exact triggers to match, if it's CLOSE then it will save actions and the rating they are given will be lesser. Now, seeing this all, it works doesn't it?

Comment: This approach is known as "nearest neighbor" (q.v.), and is outperformed (in many cases) by algorithms such as SVM and neural networks. This is an empirical fact.

Comment: But why is it outperformed? - What does it do different? Also it works doesn't it?

Comment: No, it actually doesn't work as well as other methods. You can try it out and see for yourself.

Comment: What would happen with my method?

Comment: It will have poor performance in many cases, for example digit recognition. This is an empirical fact. Stating that it works doesn't make it so. At this point it is pointless to advance the discussion any further before you actually test your ideas and see if they have empirical merit compared to other approaches.

Comment: But wait, by digit rec. do you mean on the computer if a number is close to another number? That is deviating away from taking a whole picture of pixels because we don't work that way, you're talking about computer things.

Comment: I mean digit recognition. For example, given a photo of an envelope with an address written on it, determine the zip code. This involves recognizing the individual digits making up the zip code.

Comment: Matching pictures has no zip codes where are you getting this from...this is supposed to be about taking a image or soundtrack of bits and matching them to the pre-installation and the more it matches the more it saves actions and "prefers it more".

Comment: @FriendlyPerson44 what Y/Filmus is saying is that of course all algorithms will try to match an input to a pattern and do an action. **But** how exactly this matching is done can be critical. Nearest-neighbour is one simple matching algorithm, but it cannot account for more complex inter-relations which other algorithms (like neural networks) can account for. In this sense they produce different results and different abilities of generalisation